# Should I use 'value' or 'worth' or 'value worth'?

Tags: grammar

For example, which one is best phrased:

1. The current Dollar value of 10 Euro
2. The current Dollar worth of 10 Euro
3. The current Dollar value worth of 10 Euro

Or is there a better way to express the above?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence makes sense, though in English "euro" is singular, so you should use "10 euros" instead.

(Also note that in English, currency names aren't capitalised. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/why-arent-currency-names-capitalized)

If you want a slightly clearer/more verbose way of saying it, you could say "The value of 10 euros in dollars is....."

Answer (score 1):

I find all of your examples incorrect.

### **As per dictionary, 'Worth' means**

1. **equivalent in value to the sum or item specified.**

"jewellery worth £450 was taken"

2. sufficiently good, important, or interesting to be treated or regarded in the way specified.
   "the museums in the district are well worth a visit"

Therefore, you don't have to use both value & worth in the same sentence. **The current Dollar worth of 10 Euro** can be written this way

**The US dollar is worth 10 euros today**

or **At present the dollar is worth 10 euros**

**If you want to use 'value', then the answer given by Freddie can be used**

Comment: Note that currency is not capitalised (See the link in my answer).

Comment: "At present Dollar is worth 10 euros" is ungrammatical: you need some kind of article or other specifier before dollar (which should also be lower-case, as mentioned). You could say "At present one dollar is worth 10 euros" or "At present a dollar is worth 10 euros" or even "At present the dollar is worth 10 euros" (referring to the dollar as an abstract entity).